# Calculate first and last date per each variable using R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset containing economic information on individual countries. I would like to retrieve the first and latest date per each variable. Above the dataset

```
#I have this

country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT","BE","BE","CY","CY","CY")
date_yq    <- c("2001Q1","2001 Q2","2001 Q3","2001 Q4","2003 Q2","2003 Q4","2006 Q1","2006 Q2","2006 Q3")
gdp     <- c(NA,NA,1.2,1.3,NA,2.7,3.1,3.2,3.3)
invest  <- c(NA,120,140,160,NA,210,NA,310,NA)
df      <- data.frame(country,date_yq,gdp,invest)
df$date_yq <- as.yearqtr(date_yq)
View(df)

# I would like to have this

country       <- c("AT","BE","CY")
gdp_min_date  <- c("2001Q3","2003 Q4","2006 Q1")
gdp_max_date  <- c("2001Q4","2003 Q4","2006 Q3")
invest_min_date  <- c("2001Q2","2003 Q4","2006 Q2")
invest_max_date  <- c("2001 Q4","2003 Q4","2006 Q2")
df_dates      <- data.frame(country,gdp_min_date,gdp_max_date,invest_min_date,invest_max_date)
View(df_dates)
```

Can you suggest something to solve this? I've been looking around but I couldn't find any solution. Thank you.

EDIT: I am not looking to retrieve the minimum value of GDP but the first available date per each country.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided all `library()` packages that you have used in your PO. It took me a while to work out that `as.yearqtr()` might be from `zoo` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df_dates <- df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarize(
    gdp_min_date = min(date_yq[!is.na(gdp)]),
    gdp_max_date = max(date_yq[!is.na(gdp)]), 
    invest_min_date =min(date_yq[!is.na(invest)]),
    invest_max_date =max(date_yq[!is.na(invest)])  
  )

df_dates
```

Comment: I edited the question, the problem is that I am not looking to retrieve the minimum value of GDP but instead the first available date per each country, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please let me know if your have any problems with the code.